# When i click anything on github like starring a repo, opening any file, this thing pops up , how to use it (This /*sema stuff)

Tags: git, github, open-source

[image]

I could not understand the error and it is also not what this sema stuff which pops up trying to fix any issue!
Help me to reach out to it, so that after every click i need not to manually off this pop up window.

Comment: Is that a browser plugin or something?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be some sort of browser extension or other software from [Sema Software](https://www.semasoftware.com/).  There is nothing like this automatically on GitHub, so it's definitely something on your machine.

If you don't want to use this software and it's bothering you, check your browser extensions to see if it's present, and if so, uninstall it.  Otherwise, uninstall it in the normal way for your operating system.  If it's a corporate machine and you cannot, contact your IT department and ask them to have it removed.